# Make scrollview in layout (crash)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a screen scrollable with scroll view but my application keeps crashing.
What I've done is to replace RelativeLayout by ScrollView, but it doesn't work.
I need your help with this. Here is the code of the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/background01"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:background="@drawable/lightcontainer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mainTitle1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowRadius="1.5"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to programming, so I don't know what you mean by stacktrace.

Comment: what does the error log say. When it crashes, what appears at the bottom.

Comment: I'm using Genymotion for my tests so I can't see any log.
It's, apparently, because of ScrollView. I just replace RelativeLayout by ScrollView on the code above, but it crashes when I run the app on the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is not an scrollable view it's just a relative layout. Try to put your code inside a ScrollView component, like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

    <!-- PUT YOUR CODE HERE -->

</ScrollView>
```

Make sure you close all tags correctly as well (your relative layout is not closed).

```
<RelativeLayout>
 Content
</RelativeLayout> <-- This closing tag is always necessary
```

Comment: <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background01"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
</ScrollView>

Comment: Remove the semicolons ';' at the end of lines from xml code, my recommendation is to separate properties (1 per line). Take in mind that ScrollView allows you to scroll only when the elements to be represented cannot fit in the screen.